# NPE in SSLSocketImpl.getEnabledCipherSuites

Tags: java, ssl, stack-trace

I am using Apache HTTP client in multiple workers, and it looks like there is some kind of race condition (stacktrace is at the end). I am puzzled as googling the stacktrace does not provide any hint (yet). Using Java 1.7.0-b147 64bits on Linux.

1. Am I doing something wrong here?
2. Are there known, efficient alternatives to Sun's implementations of `SSLSocket`?

**Edit:**
Maybe not useful, but the calling code is like :

```
public String call() {
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(aUrl);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
```

in which the httpClient is shared to all callables.

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2320)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.getSSLParameters(SSLSocket.java:614)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSSLParameters(SSLSocketImpl.java:2406)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.<init>(SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:65)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:236)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.<init>(Handshaker.java:191)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.<init>(ClientHandshaker.java:104)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1217)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:634)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:608)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
```

Comment: Are you doing something wrong where? in what code?

Comment: @EJP in using HttpClient for HTTPS in multiple threads; although I suppose HttpClient is not the cause of the issue there

Comment: How about you take the hint and ***post the code?*** How else do you expect to get any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a JDK issue. We had this issue when running JDK 1.7.0_u4 and it was resolved after upgrading to JDK 1.7.0_u25.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will try the upgrade. Do you know if there is a related bug report on Oracle's tracker?

Comment: I was unable to find it in Oracle's tracker. Java7 was released more than two years ago and the release candidate is even older. Upgrading to a more recent JDK version is likely a good idea.